# Angular routing not working for direct requests / links

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Hej.

I've written some routes for my Angular app.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'blog', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'blog', component: PostsComponent },
  { path: 'blog/:id', component: PostComponent }
];
```

now the base href is configured as

```
<base href="/">
```

and as I want to host the app on something like ***domain.tld/blog*** I use this command to build the sources

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer --base-href=/blog/
```

My issue now: Opening ***domain.tld/blog*** works like a charm, as does referring the any sub page like ***domain.tld/blog/1***. BUT only as I transition from one page to another. When I try to access e.g. ***domain.tld/blog/1*** with direct linking, a 404 is thrown.

Any suggestions how to solve this, guys? 
Thanks a lot, appreciate it

Comment: Why do you have same components for both the routes?

Comment: What web server do you deploy (nginx / apache)? You must config the web server redirecting to index.html from child route

Comment: You need to configure you server to redirect all request for `domain.tld/blog/*` to `domain.tld/blog/index.html`

Comment: @Sajeetharan One has an id, one has not, but it's the same route...

Comment: And it is not the same component. Notice the subtle difference in spelling.

Thanks for pointing that out, it obviously makes sense to redirect as Angular otherwise can't handle that requests.